# Using C++ class from C# in Linux

Tags: c#, c++, linux

I am using quantconnect engine, which is written in C#, I have a library for broker messaging system written in C++, basically a class with setup, run, send message methods.

What I am trying to do is to somehow use the class written in C++ in C#. How can I do it? One of ideas is to convert C++ to C and then C to C++.

I know that there is easy way to do so in windows but I think on Linux it's not available.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/how-to-wrap-native-class-for-use-by-csharp?view=msvc-170

I was also thinking that maybe instead of trying to port C++ class I could make some kind of binary that is running as a separate process and C# code is communicating, calling its functions. Is there any technology that enables me it?

Thanks for help and please keep in mind that I am a beginner so the easiest solutions are the best for me.

Comment: You can use P/Invoke on Linux. P/Invoke is a .NET feature that allows calling C functions. You could write a C library that wraps your C++ functions, and call the C functions from C#. If you want to go the two-process + message passing route, take a look at gRPC.